# Is it worth mentioning your advisors' qualifications in your CV?

Tags: resume, research

I'm presently an undergraduate at college, started my junior year, and have done some internships at various places (one remote as a software dev, two at college as an undergrad researcher, and one abroad as a research assistant).

In my CV, I'm putting my internship advisors' name (and a hyperlink on that name which links to their current profiles) when I list my internships. Should I also write their qualifications, where applicable (Ph.D from XYZ university)?

I was pondering this because some of the profs I have worked with are PhDs from prestigious places (Carnegie Mellon, KAIST etc), so perhaps along with saying that I having worked with them (and adding a hyperlink to their current profiles) for a sizeable duration, the qualification adds a slightly better emphasis. The qualification is also written on the links I added, but I'm not sure if somebody looking at my CV will go to those links and see, so I thought of just mentioning it separately.

Is this recommended, or might this be redundant?

Comment: Welcome to the site sm094. This site is mainly for questions relating to "conventional" workplaces and academia-specific matters, especially those concerning titles, forms of address and references are off-topic here and I've closed this accordingly. I would suggest submitting an updated and clearer version of your question to our sister site [academia.se]. Ordinarily we would migrate your question for you but [as discussed in Academia chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39929180#39929180) that would largely invalidate the answers here.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm putting my internship advisors' name

Generally speaking, you shouldn't put the names of your boss or advisor in your resume to begin with. Your resume should advertise who *you* are, not who your boss was. Of course, this doesn't apply in special cases, for example, if you were the Personal Assistant to a movie star or a politician.

I have known that the culture in academia is different, and who you have worked with is given a lot more importance there than on the business side. If you are applying to jobs mainly in academia, this advice may not apply.

Comment: Yes, I'm mostly looking at academia.

Comment: @sm094 You probably want to flag the moderator to migrate your question to Academia SE. (Please do not cross-post this question.)

Answer (score 1):

I would spin this in the experience/project sections where you're stating what you accomplished:

"Reporting to/Working under John Smith, Ph.D., I defined parts of the Curriculum Vitae where it would be appropriate to name drop."

If they're influential in the field, you'll (A) know this, and (B) benefit from the association in part. Don't tell us everyone you've ever worked with, though, because name-dropping becomes tiring at a point and not every association will benefit you.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote, this is fairly common.

Comment: Trolls, @CMosychuk. There, I explained it. I gave you an upvote, though, for what it's worth, because I wholeheartedly agree with your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Generally no, unless your advisor is coming with you to your new job. When I review resumes, I dont't really care about the achievements of your (soon-to-be) previous boss. I'd focus on yours.

Though, I'm not in academia and other cultures may apply. If you believe the customs in academia are different, ask a more experienced colleague.

Comment: Yes, I'm mostly looking at academia.

Comment: Of course you'd focus on my achievements, but if I've probably done work with a great company / person or so, wouldn't that matter? (as compared to working with something lesser known)